# Placement of bullets between 2 items

Tags: formatting

I am using a [resume template](https://github.com/sb2nov/resume/blob/master/sourabh_bajaj_resume.tex) and currently the bullets for the resumeSubheading entry appear somewhere in the middle of the 1st and 3rd entry. Somewhat like this:

[image]

I want them to be directly before the first entry *(before Google in the example)*

I tried experimenting with the code

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

Here changing the value of 0.97 before `\textwidth` has no effect unless it is 0.99 after which the bullets appear somwhat like this:

[image]

Nothing else seems to work. Can somebody help me with this, how to place the bullet directly before the company name?

```
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Google}{Mountain View, CA}
      {Software Engineer}{Oct 2016 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Tensorflow}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines, as well as a set of language-specific SDKs for constructing pipelines and runners.}
      \resumeItemListEnd
```

Overleaf link: `<removed>`

Comment: @KJO yes I experimented with most values, the link for the full github template is there and I am also adding the overleaf link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup looks very strange but

```
 \item \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
```

will make the first row of the `tabular*` align with the bullet from the item label.

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks everything over in the template, although it might be the standalone solution. Can you help with regards to this specific template?

Comment: @KJO oops thanks, updated

Comment: @IshanSrivastava sorry t was in wrong place see KJO's comment